# Фиксация шапки таблицы

Tags: html, css

Есть таблица (пример):

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
    <tr style="position:fixed;">
      <td>Имя</td>
      <td>Фамилия</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Иван 1</td>
      <td>иванов 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Иван 1</td>
      <td>иванов 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Иван 1</td>
      <td>иванов 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Иван 1</td>
      <td>иванов 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Иван 1</td>
      <td>иванов 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Шапка теряет свою ширину относительно последующих строк. Можно как то сделать, чтобы ширина не изменялась?

Comment: Указание ширины напрямую не подходит!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Зафиксировать можно только блочный элемент (на table не действует так как хотелось бы). `position: fixed;` означает, что блок позиционируется относительно экрана.

Можно что-то такого попробовать, если очень нужно:

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="padding-top:1rem;">
    <tr style="position:fixed; top: 0; width:100%;">
      <td style="display: inline-block; width: 49%;">Имя</td>
      <td style="display: inline-block; width: 49%;">Фамилия</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Иван 1</td>
      <td>иванов 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Иван 1</td>
      <td>иванов 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Иван 1</td>
      <td>иванов 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Иван 1</td>
      <td>иванов 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Иван 1</td>
      <td>иванов 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий вариант:

```
<section class="">
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
          <th>
            <div>Имя</div>
          </th>
          <th>
            <div>Фамилия</div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Иван 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Иван 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Иван 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Иван 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Иван 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Иван 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Иван 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Иван 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

и

```
html, body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 37px;
  background: #500;
}

.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width:100%;
}
td + td {
  border-left:1px solid #eee;
}
td, th {
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
th {
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th div{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 25px;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
  line-height: normal;
  border-left: 1px solid #800;
}
```

Пример
https://jsfiddle.net/h0qp3efw/

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 37px;
  background: #555;
  width:90%;
}

.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width:100%;
}
td + td {
  border-left:1px solid #eee;
}
td, th {
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
th {
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th div{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 25px;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
  line-height: normal;
  border-left: 1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Шапка таблицы</title>
<meta name="description" content="Test">
<meta name="Robots" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="i.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<h2>Шапка таблицы</h2>
<section class="">
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
          <th><div>Имя</div></th><th><div>Фамилия</div></th><th><div>Отчество 1</div></th><th><div>Отч09876</div></th><th><div>Отч56789</div></th><th><div>Отч2345</div></th><th><div>Отч 3</div></th><th><div>Отчество 4</div></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Иван 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Иван 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>иванов иванов иванов иванов</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Иван 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>иванов иванов иванов иванов</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Иван 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>иванов иванов иванов иванов</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Иван 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>иванов иванов иванов иванов</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Иван 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>иванов иванов иванов иванов</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Иван 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>иванов иванов иванов иванов</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Иван 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>иванов иванов иванов иванов</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Иван 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>иванов иванов иванов иванов</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Иван 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>иванов иванов иванов иванов</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Иван 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>иванов 1</td>
          <td>иванов иванов иванов иванов</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

На реальной таблице "шапку" срывает