# Фиксация заголовка таблицы HTML

Tags: html, css, table, таблицы

При  фиксации заголовка таблицы воспользовался вот этим: [Фиксация шапки таблицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/567353/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B)
В моем случае таблицы занимает часть экрана и обёрнута в div. В результате при прокрутке не видно последние строки. Как это побороть?

Comment: Можете предоставить пример вашего случая реализации?

Comment: Весь контент подается на клиента на google apps, наверное возможно, нужно писать отдельное приложение. Думаю я решу эту задачу, ограничив высоту дивов с учетом полей. На самом деле, когда столбцов больше 4, данные в tbody и thead рознятся,столбцы в шапке на сходятся со столбцами в теле.